# How can I get Syntastic to recognize newer Ruby syntax?

Tags: vim, ruby

I'm using Syntastic in Vim, and it highlights newer Ruby syntax as errors. For example, if I use required keyword arguments (introduced in Ruby 2.1), like this:

```
def distance(from:, to:)
  # whatever
end
```

... it highlights the definition line and says "unexpected ','".

How can I get it to recognize this as valid Ruby syntax? I've already updated `~/.vim/syntax/ruby.vim`.

Comment: Note: `~/.vim/syntax/ruby.vim` has nothing to do with *checking* syntax in files; it's for syntax *highlighting*. See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-vim-syntax-plugins

Answer (score 9):

## Specify the ruby executable for Syntastic

Syntastic calls `ruby -c` to check the syntax of a file, so the errors it shows depends on which version of ruby its using.

You can point it to the one you want to use like this:

```
let g:syntastic_ruby_exec = 'path/to/ruby/executable'
```

**NOTE:** on newer versions of Syntastic:

```
let g:syntastic_ruby_mri_exec = 'path/to/ruby/executable'
```

---

`$ type ruby` will tell you where your current Ruby executable is. Ruby installers have their own conventions about where they place their binaries. Eg:

- [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) puts ruby installations in `~/.rubies` and specific versions at paths like `~/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby`
- [RVM](https://rvm.io/) puts ruby installations in `~/.rvm/rubies` and specific versions at paths like `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby`

Comment: FYI: if you are using rvm it would be `let g:syntastic_ruby_exec = '~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby'`

Comment: @Ben good point - updated answer

Comment: For the newer version of syntastic, it's: `let g:syntastic_ruby_mri_exec='path/to/ruby/executable'`

Comment: If you're using rbenv you should be able to do `let g:syntastic_ruby_exec = '~/.rbenv/shims/ruby'` so that when ruby versions switch it should automatically pick it up, I think.

Comment: Nice @Thermatix.. I used `system("rbenv which ruby")` in my .vimrc

Answer (score 4):

Using terminal macvim I also had this problem, which was compounded by the fact that I was using zsh, which for some reason was **not** respecting the rvm binary I gave syntastic.  I realized that my paths where incorrect when running `!echo $PATH` in terminal macvim, I had several system paths appended to the top that were not in my regular shell still causing the default MRI to load.

To fix this, I did not need to specify the syntax checker at all in my .vimrc, however I had to update how zsh started.  Using the thread at: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-and-PATH-td3388705.html I ended up simply running `sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zprofile` and now everything works and my paths are correct in mvim.  This should also solve the problem of updating syntastic when installing a new ruby version via rvm.

Comment: This is the actual fix! The problem is because of a [caveat with zsh installed via brew in OSX](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/issues/196#issuecomment-23825139).

Comment: Random question - isn't "terminal macvim" just vim? What benefits do you gain using Macvim in the terminal over using plain vim?

Answer (score 0):

For a Rails project.

- Set the ruby version in a `.ruby-version` file at project root.
- And start your vim from the project root.

Syntastic will do the syntax check with the specified ruby version.